# Having a dynamic interface based on the value on another node

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following interface:

```
import { Facts } from './../facts/facts-interface';
import { DegreeTypes } from './../degree-types/degree-types-interface';
import { Guides } from './../guides/guides-interface';
import { TitleBodyTextImage } from './../title-body-text-image/title-body-text-image-interface';
import { ImageBlockList } from './../image-block-list/image-block-list-interface';
import { TextBlockList } from './../text-block-list/text-block-list-interface'; 
import { StudentReviews } from './../student-reviews/student-reviews-interface'; 
import { ProgramSearch } from './../program-search/program-search-interface'; 
import { Programs } from './../programs/programs-interface';
import { EmailMagnets } from './../email-magnets/email-magnets-interface';
import { Experts } from './../experts/experts-interface';
import { Facilities } from './../facilities/facilities-interface';

type AllowedComponents = "title-body-text-image" | "image-block-list" | "program-search" | "text-block-list" | "facts" | "facilities" | "student-reviews" | "experts" | "programs" | "degree-types" | "email-magnets";

interface ComponentDataMap {
 facts: Facts;
 'degree-types': DegreeTypes;
 guides: Guides;
 'title-body-text-image': TitleBodyTextImage;
 'image-block-list': ImageBlockList;
 'text-block-list': TextBlockList;
 'student-reviews': StudentReviews;
 'program-search': ProgramSearch;
 'programs': Programs;
 'email-magnets': EmailMagnets;
 'experts': Experts;
 'facilities': Facilities;
}

export interface StickyMenuWithoutSubItems {
  [x: string]: Overview | null;
}

export interface Overview {
 nav_item_name: string;
 component: AllowedComponents;
 data: ComponentDataMap[AllowedComponents];
}
```

My goal is depending on the value given on "component" will base what the interface will be for "data". For example if "component" equals "guides" then the "data" node will use the Guides interface. If "component" equals "image-block-list" then the "data" node will use the ImageBlockList interface.

And this is correctly applied. However I get errors on my template side. `Such as:Type 'StudentReviews | TitleBodyTextImage | ImageBlockList | ProgramSearch | TextBlockList | ... 5 more ... | EmailMagnets' is not assignable to type 'Guides'. Property 'list' is missing in type 'StudentReviews' but required in type 'Guides'.`

The property "list" does indeed exist in the Guides interface but not on StudentReviews and it never will. So it's like mixing and getting confused what should be in each. Is there a way to resolve this? I really don't want to have to declare "list" inside StudentReviews as that's going to look very messy.

Comment: Why not use generics, e.g. something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGKLAZ2QbwLABQAkPAmAIwBcymYUoA5gNyEC+hhoksiKA4gFdgAEwjZ8xBkNFVkIAQFsARtBYF2BTuGikUAYQD2CgA4GQEcABE4YOAFk4x3IWSks1dGUxrkUkWOpBf282Dk0CLh1eZAB5ADdoOOAIAHcAHgAVZAgAD0gQYWwAawgATwMYZEMTMwswa1sHYwA+Z2IQODiAfWBIBS6OhQhqWnoQZkIiBCNTc3BqDLUiYRs4amrZuob7RwBtDIBdUPCAGwgwZABHanjE5PSAcjdMB9aAXjaiDu7eiH7B4bIJ4YB4AGkm0xqczA1GBXjBkxWtmoEiIJAwsgemCMKDcD0mGg0hDOFwAXjcElAkqk0g8-KIXu9Pt8en0BnAhrD6RAEcRIZt5kDuS9wcQkWtPkRubIAKwEthqQjTEDYs4AOhOBgYAApLmrxWq3OQAJRqZWqiAarXa0n61Zq6WmsJAA)?